# Is it OK to return Model object to View in MVC?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

Is it right if I return a Model object from Controller method to the View to be able to set the datasource to the datagridview in the View?

I'm trying to use MVC in WinForms.

I have a wrapper class that holds two models and which I pass to the Controller.

```
public class TwoModels
    {
        public UserInfo user { get; set; }

        public List<UserInfo> Users { get; set; }

        public BindingList<MedicineProduct> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a method in my View which loads data and sets the DataGridView's datasource.

```
    private void LoadCache()
    {
        productsCache = new Products();
        productsCache = XMLToObjectToXML.LoadData(productsCache, path);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = productsCache.Products_;
        userCache = XMLToObjectToXML.LoadUser(username);
    }
```

I want to move this method to controller. But, I don't know if it's a right approach. Should I load data in controller or should I do it inside wrapper class?

Comment: Yes you can.. but there is no datasource or datagridview. There's only View

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Ensure that the ActionResult method has the same name as a view you want to return and that the view is expecting a Model object the same type as you are returning in the controller.

I would need to see some example code to help determine what you plan on achieving with use of datagridview.